# Custom method not work on HasMany relation

Tags: laravel, relation

I trying to call a custom method from a model by relation.

**User Model**:

```
class User extends Model
{
  public function files()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Files::class, 'file_id', 'id');
  }

}
```

**File Model**:

```
class Files extends Model
{
  public function cover() 
  {
     dd('blah blah');
  }
}
```

In my controller I said:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->files()->cover();
```

But I will get this error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::cover()
```

What is the problem in my code?

Comment: you copy this from your model? Because the cover method is spelled wrong.

Comment: @Miaan Thanks for your comment, no I changed the real method name here, I will update my question

Answer (score 3):

Basically you are calling your `cover()` method over the collection. That's why that is not working.

You are using  `hasMany` Laravel relationship. And this `hasMany` returns collection of related records(items). And yo can't call any model function on that directly.

But if you wan to call function on this. you need to firstly loop the items, like below example:-

```
$user = User::find(1);
foreach($user->files() as $file) {
    $file->cover();
}
```

Above code will provide you output. Try this.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I want to use this method to check and then store the cover. because I need to check the cover before insert I couldn't use `create` method, it will be an alias to create. so I couldn't overwrite to `create` method?

Comment: Your answer could show me a hint but couldn't solve my problem. I just make an up vote

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the covers of you files, you can do this :

```
$user = User::with('files.cover')->find(1);

$covers = $user->files->pluck('cover')->flatten();
```

> I want to use this method to check and then store the cover. because I need to check the cover before insert I couldn't use create method, it will be an alias to create. so I couldn't overwrite to create method?

From this, you can do the following:

```
foreach($user->files as $file){

    $cover = $file->cover()->firstOrCreate(['attribute' => $value]);

    // If you want to check if you just created the cover 
    if($cover->wasRecentlyCreated){
       // Do stuff
    }
}
```